# Problems reseting password with new email

Tags: support

I forgot my password (stupid I know) and tried to request a password change. However for some reason it's not recognizing my email, I know I changed email address a few years ago and I cannot access my old email account. I thought I changed my email address on stack overflow as well but it does not appear to have taken any effect. Additional for some reason only a few sites still recognize my login from before but I cannot for example access the chat or the stackexchange main site.

I have lost my password before but I have always been able to easily reset it, anybody know why this time is different or can someone help me fix it?

Comment: Hmm I got into my old email somehow, but it does raise the question why it is only working for my old email and now my new one?